# NLog whenRepeated filter, is it possible to add a condition?

Tags: nlog

Assuming a normal catch all file logger:

```xml
  <nlog autoReload="true">
    <targets>
      <target name="file" type="File" layout="${longdate} ${logger} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" fileName="$Log.log" archiveFileName="LogArchive.{#}.log" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Rolling" maxArchiveFiles="7" concurrentWrites="true" keepFileOpen="false" encoding="utf-8" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
      </logger>
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

When an external library is repetitively spamming exceptions and I don't want to flood my log file with them, I can exclude them like this:

```xml
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" >
      <filters>
        <when condition="equals('${logger}','SpammyLogger')" action="Ignore" />
      </filters>
    </logger>
  </rules>
```

And since the exception is sometimes caught and rethrown as innerexception by another class logger, I have better results filtering it like this:

```
        <when condition="contains('${exception}','SpammyLogger.*')" action="Ignore" />
```

This is good, but I still want to be aware when the exception happen, I would like to log it once every x seconds and then filter the rest. So I found out about the `whenRepeated` filter which do just that. I'm able to setup it by creating a second logger that match the logger:

```xml
  <rules>
    <logger name="SpammyLogger.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" final="true">
      <filters>
        <whenRepeated layout="${logger}" timeoutSeconds="30" action="Ignore" FilterCountMessageAppendFormat=" (Hits: {0})" />
        </filters>
      </logger>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>
```

This works, but again it's not filtering the rethrow innerexception, just the original logger. I would like to add it as a filter of the * logger instead of creating a second one. Or at least, be able to filter on the {exception} text instead of the logger as the previous example.

So TL;DR, since the `whenRepeated` doesn't have a condition parameter like the `when` filter, I can't use it in the same manner. I also don't quite understand why it requires a `layout` (which is a way to format the output) in a filter parameter? Is there a way to use it to filter on the content of the exception like the normal when filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a very domain specific problem, but maybe this will work:

```xml
      <rules>
        <!-- Handle output from spammy-loggers -->
        <logger name="SpammyLogger*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="file" final="true">
          <filters>
            <!-- Final ignore spammy logging without exceptions (Semi fastfilter) -->
            <when condition="'${exception:format=type}' == ''" action="IgnoreFinal" />

            <!-- Final ignore of repeated spammy exceptions (from spammy loggers) -->
            <whenRepeated layout="${exception:format=type}" timeoutSeconds="30" action="IgnoreFinal" FilterCountMessageAppendFormat=" (Hits: {0})" />
          </filters>
        </logger>

        <!-- Handle output from other loggers -->
        <logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="file">
          <filters>
            <!-- Log all good messages without exceptions (Semi fast filter) -->
            <when condition="'${exception:format=type}' == ''" action="Log" />

            <!-- Log all good messages with exceptions (Slow filter) -->
            <when condition="not contains('${exception}','SpammyLogger')" action="Log" />

            <!-- Final ignore of repeated spammy exceptions (from other loggers) -->
            <whenRepeated layout="${logger}${exception:format=type}" timeoutSeconds="30" action="IgnoreFinal" FilterCountMessageAppendFormat=" (Hits: {0})" />
          </filters>
        </logger>
      </rules>
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of inverting the condition and logging what's valid first. In the situation I don't want to ignore normal non-exception output from SpammyLogger, I can just remove the first block right? Also, I assume you added the first "semi fast filter" line with the purpose of helping performance?

Comment: Yes filtering on Logger-name is the fastest filtering. The filtering that uses `==`-compare is semi-fast without allocation. But filtering with `not contains` will do some allocation.